# Join with Pythons SQLite module is slower than doing it manually

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, apsw

I am using pythons built-in `sqlite3` module to access a database. My query executes a join between a table of 150000 entries and a table of 40000 entries, the result contains about 150000 entries again. If I execute the query in the [SQLite Manager](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/) it takes a few seconds, but if I execute the same query from Python, it has not finished after a minute. Here is the code I use:

```
cursor = self._connection.cursor()
annotationList = cursor.execute("SELECT PrimaryId, GOId " + 
                                "FROM Proteins, Annotations " +
                                "WHERE Proteins.Id = Annotations.ProteinId")
annotations = defaultdict(list)
for protein, goterm in annotationList:
    annotations[protein].append(goterm)
```

I did the `fetchall` just to measure the execution time. Does anyone have an explanation for the huge difference in performance? I am using Python 2.6.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.4.

I implemented the join manually, and this works much faster. The code looks like this:

```
cursor = self._connection.cursor()
proteinList = cursor.execute("SELECT Id, PrimaryId FROM Proteins ").fetchall()
annotationList = cursor.execute("SELECT ProteinId, GOId FROM Annotations").fetchall()
proteins = dict(proteinList)
annotations = defaultdict(list)
for protein, goterm in annotationList:
    annotations[proteins[protein]].append(goterm)
```

So when I fetch the tables myself and then do the join in Python, it takes about 2 seconds. The code above takes forever. Am I missing something here?

I tried the same with [apsw](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/), and it works just fine (the code does not need to be changed at all), the performance it great. I'm still wondering why this is so slow with the `sqlite3`-module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a discussion about it here: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg253067.html

It seems that there is a performance bottleneck in the sqlite3 module. There is an [advice](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg253144.html) how to make your queries faster:

- make sure that you do have indices on the join columns
- use pysqlite

Comment: I am using python 2.6.5. It says on the PySqlite homepage that the `sqlite3` package that comes with Python is the same as `PySqlite`, but it doesn't say which version.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the schema of the tables in question, but I think there might be a problem with indexes, specifically not having an index on Proteins.Id or Annotations.ProteinId (or both).

Create the SQLite indexes like this

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_Proteins_Id ON Proteins (Id)
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_Annotations_ProteinId ON Annotations (ProteinId)
```

Comment: The Ids are create as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEYS`, meaning there are indexes on them by default. The identical schema yields way better performance when I use `apsw` instead of Pythons `sqlite3` module, so I doubt that the schema is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this because I am noticing the same issue and we are now 2022...

In my own application I am using python3 and sqlite3 to do some data wrangling on large databases (>100000 rows * >200 columns). In particular, I have noticed that my 3 table inner join clocks in around ~12 minutes of run time in python, whereas running the same join query in sqlite3 from the CLI runs in ~100 seconds. All the join predicates are properly indexed and the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN indicates that the added time is most likely because I am using SELECT *, which is a necessary evil in my particular context.

The performance discrepancy caused me to pull my hair out all night until I realized there is a quick fix from here: [Running a Sqlite3 Script from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758769/running-a-sqlite3-script-from-command-line). This is definitely a workaround at best, but I have research due so this is my fix.

1. Write out the query to an .sql file (I am using f-strings to pass variables in so I used an example with {foo} here)

```
fi = open("filename.sql", "w")
fi.write(f"CREATE TABLE {Foo} AS SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.KeyColumn = Table1.KeyColumn INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.KeyColumn = Table1.KeyColumn;")
fi.close()
```

2. Run os.system from inside python and send the .sql file to sqlite3

```
os.system(f"sqlite3 {database} < filename.sql")
```

Make sure you close any open connection before running this so you don't end up locked out and you'll have to re-instantiate any connection objects afterward if you're going back to working in sqlite within python.

Hope this helps and if anyone has figured the source of this out, please link to it!